# Backup of Inline or managed Policies AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there any way to take backup of all inline or managed policies of a IAM user in AWS ?? I need to do this for security purpose so before deleting any IAM user i need to take backup of inline policies.

Comment: The short answer is yes - you can get that information using aws CLI or write code in any [supported sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/). If you tried something already and it didn't work then post your code here.

Comment: I tired below , but i need to take the backup of these policies aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name

Comment: It will be easier to use something like [boto](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to write a script which will extract the required information.

Comment: @Raf if you have any boto script can you please provide me ?? thanks in advance ...

Comment: iam.list_attached_user_policies(UserName='user_name')

But i need to get the policy data/details also ,like what inside in inline policy Please help me out

Comment: The way it usually works on SO is people post their code and the community tries to fix the problems, rather than writing the code for you :)